# Add class on click to a unordered list item to change the background color of list item and at the same time remove it from other list item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFcix.png)I am trying to add a class on the unordered list item when I click on it and a the same time it should be removing the same class from other list item.

I have tried using the below JavaScript logic but I am not getting the desired results. When I am including `e.preventDefault()` then it is not redirecting me to the desired page but it is removing and adding the class to the list item. And when I am excluding `e.preventDefault()` then it is redirecting me to the desired page but it is not removing and adding the class.

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('li');
links.forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // PreventDefault to prevent redirect
    e.preventDefault();
    links.forEach(async function(element) {
      // element.preventDefault()
      await element.classList.remove('active');
    });
    this.classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

```css
li:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: rgb(91, 19, 114);
  border-radius: 2vh;
}

.active {
  background-color: rgb(132, 2, 175);
}
```

```html
<div id="user-account-menu">
  <ul class="side-nav">
    <li class="">
      <a href="/me">
        Settings
        <img class="navItems-icons" src="img/icons/settings.png" alt="settings">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="/create-user">
        Create User
        <img class="navItems-icons" src="img/icons/create-user.png" alt="create-user">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If the page redirect is intended to happen when you click one of the links, then your issue with changing the class is moot, as HTML is stateless. You would need to set the class only when the page loads, not when the element is clicked.

Comment: Please try removing async/await in internal forEach, it should be synchronous and run before it will propagate to default behaviour (redirecting)

Comment: I totaly agree with @Rory no need to change class if clicked you are redirected to a New page and won t see the changes. Maybe you mean on hover

Comment: Guys, I'd agree with you for default redirection - but we never know maybe he has #dashed-redirection or interrupt and process redirections in a custom way in other part of code. I agree for "default" redirection it doesn't make sense, but if menu (for any reason) is not going to be hidden on redirection, then look at my answer below.

Comment: @Rory yes absolutely,  if he does the changes (by keeping e.prevent.Default) but still wants to redirect why doing it

Comment: @MaxímG. given the tags on the question, the mention of the word 'redirect' and not some other SPA-related term, and the plain HTML, that seems very, very unlikely to be the case

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have attached a screenshot in my questions. In the screenshot you can see a vertical menu-navbar on the left side. The list item with the text 'Settings' has the class 'active' as default. What I want is when I click any other list item then the background color of the clicked list item changes and also the page which is assigned to the particular list item should be displayed in the right side of the screen.

Comment: If you want a true "page" that would likely require a iframe to contain it (on the right hand side) otherwise it is perhaps just "content" not a "page"

Answer (score -1):

Please remove async/await from internal forEach. Without async/await it will run synchronously before propagated default behaviour (redirecting) takes action.

I tried it that way, and it works, it removes 'active' class from other list item before redirecting (I can see it for a little moment before redirection occurs).

**UPDATE:**
In the comment OP also asked content to be opened on the right, keeping links visible on the left. So I've updated my answer by adding frame for content, and targeting link to that content.

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('li');
links.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        links.forEach(async function(element) {
            element.classList.remove('active');
        });
        this.classList.add('active');
    });
});
```

```css
li:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: rgb(91, 19, 114);
  border-radius: 2vh;
}

.active {
  background-color: rgb(132, 2, 175);
}

#container {
  display: flex;
}

iframe[name=page-content] {
    flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="user-account-menu">
        <ul class="side-nav">
            <li class="">
                <a href="https://example.com/" target="page-content">
                    Settings
                    <img class="navItems-icons" src="img/icons/settings.png" alt="settings">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="https://wikipedia.com/" target="page-content">
                    Create User
                    <img class="navItems-icons" src="img/icons/create-user.png" alt="create-user">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <iframe name="page-content"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I hope OP will have some custom processing of redirection (or could be just #dash redirection within same page or any custom processing like SPA routing), so that menu will not be hidden and all those will make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the help but this is not working. I have attached a screenshot in my questions. In the screenshot you can see a vertical menu-navbar on the left side. The list item with the text 'Settings' has the class 'active' as default. What I want is when I click any other list item then the background color of the clicked list item changes and also the page which is assigned to the particular list item should be displayed in the right side of the screen.

Comment: @Siraj Saifi, I've updated my answer to open content in a different frame (next to links), not replacing main frame with the links themselves. Active class works fine as you described - on click it removes from other links and add it to clicked link. Without e.preventDefault(). If it works for you, can you please mark it as correct answer and upvote it? If you need anything else - please let me know. I changed the URLs to external (example.com, wikipedia) so that you can run here and see it works fine. Of course, in your solution please change them back to internal /me and /create-user. Thanks